# What is RP PIO in DPC?

Tags: pci

ex:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1869423

```
[ 32.338206] pcieport 0000:2d:00.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #3, RPExt- PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 0, DL_ActiveErr+
```